# linq to sql select specific cell

Tags: c#, winforms, linq, linq-to-sql

i'm doing a project using local DB and linq to sql.

its a win form which 1st receive product model and quantity of that model.

after that,user have to select models in a form and then start to insert serial numbers(equal to quantity).

my problem is i want users  to select model ID and i got the quantity number,so that i can use it for a loop which takes serial numbers.

i want to use column quantity as a counter.
i design this column as int,but i cant use it .

its not happening via this code :

```
    private void Serials_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        comboBox1.DataSource = show.linqpros;
    }
    DataClassesDataContext show = new DataClassesDataContext(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=C:\product.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30");
    linqpro serial = new linqpro();

    private void addSerial_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {



        var count = 1;
        string selected = comboBox1.Text;
        var query = from q in show.linqpros where (selected==serial.ModelID) select serial.Quantity;
        count = Convert.ToInt32(query);
        for (int i = 1; i >= count; i++)
        {
            string best = selected;
             addserial addserial = new addserial(best);
             addserial.ShowDialog();
        }
    }
```

This is my table :

[image]

this is the error :

[image]

Comment: @GrantWinney no,it gives me an error : 
Input string was not in a correct format.
in count =convert ...

Comment: @GrantWinney i attached the error

Comment: @GrantWinney do you have any idea what to do instead ? i wrote  what im  trying to do  !

Comment: @GrantWinney now i understand what you asking ! i changed both code and error picture ! whats wrong now !!

Answer (score 0):

You cast the query itsself. That's not a number because you are using a where clause it can result multiple rows.

You either need to get the count of the query if you need the number of occurences

Replace

```
count = Convert.ToInt32(query);
```

with

```
count = Convert.ToInt32(query.Count());
```

But reading the question better, it seems you need to modify your query to return only the quantity of the selected row:

```
var query = from q in show.linqpros where (selected==serial.ModelID) select serial.Quantity;
```

Into something line

```
show.Linqpros.Single(s=>s.ModelID == selected).Quantity
```

Comment: exactly thats what i want,i want the quantity for that specific row,to use it as a counter!

Comment: the update shows how to do this. Be carefull: it will trow an exception in case the ModelID does not exist. Use SingleOrDefault in other cases